# What is the name of the component that is on top of the nav bar. Commonly used to share promotional news. Refer picture

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am interested in sharing some promotional information with the users of my site and want to make a bar similar to the one in the photo attached.

What is the component called and is it available in bootstrap?
Thanks!

For reference see http://getbootstrap.com/, top banner stating "Bootstrap 4 is coming"

Comment: You will have to custom style it. Its not a Bootstrap component.

Comment: You should include a static screenshot here, or this question will be completely useless when the page changes.

Comment: @Eiko I wasn't able to add a picture due to some points restriction

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can achieve "Bootstrap 4 is coming" using following code, no need extra special component

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <!-- your content here  Bootstrap 4 is coming -->
 </div>
</div>
```